# Pervasive SQL reuses a deleted primary key

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

I came across a very odd behavior of PSQL (v11) recently:

If I create a table with an identity column, add some records and then delete the last row, this rows key will be **reused!**

```
create table "MyTable" (id identity not null, name varchar(50));

insert into "MyTable" (name) values ('Row 1');
insert into "MyTable" (name) values ('Row 2');
insert into "MyTable" (name) values ('Row 3');

select * from "MyTable"
```

so far so good

```
          id   name                                              
 ===========   ============
           1   Row 1                                             
           2   Row 2                                             
           3   Row 3
```

then when I delete "Row 3"

```
delete from "MyTable" where id = 3;
```

and add a new row

```
insert into "MyTable" (name) values ('Row 4');
```

I am surprised to get

```
         id   name                                              
===========   ==============
          1   Row 1                                             
          2   Row 2                                             
 !!! ---> 3   Row 4
```

Is there a way to change the server configuration to **prevent this behavior**. I would also be glad for any other suggestion **to create a reliably unique integer** in pervasive SQL.

Comment: Look into SQL sequences ;-)

Comment: PSQL provides no sequence functionality afaik and trying something like a central sequence store is pretty problematic since you get page or even complete table locks all the time.
Do you have any pervasive specific experience implementing sequences (other than using a CISAM unmanaged call)?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: I remember this behavior being reported as an issue within a transaction on the Btrieve side(customer was inserting 1000's of records in a transaction, aborting the transaction, and trying to get the autoincrement value and was getting 1 instead of the number of records inserted). As I recall, this was deemed expected behavior.  I don't remember it being an issue with the SQL side though.  What interface are you using?  There is no way to turn off the reuse of key values

Comment: @mirtheil it seems just like that - there is a pretty long article about when the AUTOINC field gets "lowered" in the [DataTypes](http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/sqlref/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqldtype.htm) section of the pv 13 documentation.
but it seems that they did not add a way to turn that behavior off. I am using **ODBC** BTW.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that documentation was added after the issue I described.

Comment: ^^ sounds like the pervasive way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Autoincrement` documentation ([here](http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/sqlref/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqldtype.htm#136773)), this seems to be expected behavior. Specifically, in the documentation, it says:

> If you indicate that you want the database engine to assign the next
>   value by entering a zero (0) value in an insert or update, the
>   database simply finds the highest number, adds 1, and inserts the
>   resulting value.
>   Because the highest number is "2" in the example give, the next autoincrement value will be "3".
>   The only way to prevent this behavior within autoincrement usage would be to specify the value on insert.

If you really want something unique, you can use the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` described in the documentation [here](http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/sqldtype.htm#136428).
Here's an example:

```
create table "MyTable" (id identity not null, gid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER default newid(),  name varchar(50));

insert into "MyTable" (name) values ('Row 1');
insert into "MyTable" (name) values ('Row 2');
insert into "MyTable" (name) values ('Row 3');

select * from "mytable";
delete from "MyTable" where id = 3;
insert into "MyTable" (name) values ('Row 4');
select * from "mytable";
```

And the results:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
         id   gid                                    name                                              
===========   ====================================   ==================================================
          1   1F74A3E5-6EFC-4382-81DA-94F58710AD73   Row 1                                             
          2   B5FEFA7A-F85B-486A-A7CA-9615EAD1A601   Row 2                                             
          3   E327B2CF-D01D-4039-BB83-CAD966C72131   Row 3                                             


<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
         id   gid                                    name                                              
===========   ====================================   ==================================================
          1   1F74A3E5-6EFC-4382-81DA-94F58710AD73   Row 1                                             
          2   B5FEFA7A-F85B-486A-A7CA-9615EAD1A601   Row 2                                             
          3   66F0E55C-52CF-4183-87EE-2C0FDD6E45B6   Row 4
```

Comment: this is certainly a way to get unique values but I am afraid I need the data type to stay integer (this is for an existing solution where refactoring the code is very unlikely)

Comment: As you've said, this seems to be documented behavior.  Are you seeing a problem with it in your existing code?

Comment: it's kind of an edge case: some of our PKs are used by 3rd party programs and we don't want risk reassigning a key that might be referenced somewhere. That's why we implemented an *unmanaged CISAM sequence generator* that works fine but is impossible to use through SQL...